# Hide symbol(s) in Shared Object from LD

Tags: gcc, linker, solaris, shared-libraries, ld

I have two third-party libraries occasionally having the same symbol name exported. When the executable is loaded, *ld* usually picks the wrong one and I getting crash as a result. I cannot do too much about the content of these libraries, so may be there is a way to instruct *ld* how to find the proper imlementation ?

OS - Solaris 10, my program is built by autoconf/autotools/gcc, conflicting libraries are *libclntsh* (part of Oracle driver) and OpenLDAP. Unfortuinately, I cannot use Oracle's implementation of LDAP client - it lacks many features OpenLDAP has.

Edited: The linkage is as following: libclntsh.so->A.so->MAIN<-B.so<-libldap_r.so

Comment: Hi Dmitry.  Look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909528/how-can-i-remove-a-symbol-from-a-shared-object).  Apparently, you can use [`objcopy -N foo`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_objcopy.htm) to delete a shared object's symbols.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need to link in both shared libraries at compile time (which isn't clear from your question), you can use `-Bdirect` for the shared library. This will record for all symbols from the shared library where they had been found; if then at run-time a second definition of the symbol appears (from the other shared library), it will be ignored.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to set the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to the library whose symbols should take precedence.  (If that library has shared library dependencies of its own, you may need to preload all of its dependencies; just set `LD_PRELOAD` to the list of dependent libraries, separated by spaces.)