# How can I remove a symbol from a shared object?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

Using GCC, how can I remove a symbol from a shared object after I've created the shared object? If I have three files in C manipulating symbol `foo()` like:

```
// a.c
int foo() { return 0xdead; }
int baz() { return 1; }
```

and

```
// b.c
int foo() { return 0xbeef; }
int bar() { return 0; }
```

and

```
// c.c
#include "stdio.h"
extern int foo();
extern int bar();
extern int baz();
int main() { printf("0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x\n",foo(),bar(),baz()); return 0; }
```

Then I compile and run like:

```
% gcc a.c --shared -fPIC -o a.so
% gcc b.c --shared -fPIC -o b.so
% setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH . # export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. for bash systems
% gcc c.c a.so b.so -o c
% ./c
0xdead, 0x0, 0x1
```

How can I make it so that `a.so` no longer has symbol `foo()` after I've created `a.so`?  I want  the `foo()` defined in `b.so` to be used instead of `a.so` *by deleting the `foo()` symbol from `a.so`*.  After `foo()` is deleted from `a.so`, rerunning `c` should generate a printout of:

```
0xbeef, 0x0, 0x1
```

In this toy example, I know I can simply re-order the libary names when I compile `c.c` with `a.so` and `b.so`, but how can I actually delete the symbol from `a.so`?  I imagine that after deleting `foo()` from `a.so`, this grep of the [nm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) output would yield nothing:

```
nm -a a.so | grep foo
```

Whereas right now it returns:

```
000000000000063c T foo
```

Comment: Why do you tell your GCC to compile a.so and b.so with your c.c ? Shared libraries are not supposed to be linked to your binary, that's what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for.

Comment: Maybe `objcopy` has some functionality that you need?

Comment: Have you looked more fully at `strip`? I believe you can target particular symbols in a file with `-R`...

Comment: Hi Eregrith. You're right, I should use `-la -lb`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to use the `-N` (`--strip-symbol`) option of [objcopy](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objcopy) to achieve what you want:

```
$ objcopy -N foo a.so
```

Answer (score 2):

Symbol visibility seems like a superior solution to select which functions are up for runtime linking and which are local to the library but still "extern" declared to allow usage from other .c files that comprise the library - http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility .