# List all symbols usable by ld linker

Tags: linux, gcc, intel-fortran, nm, readelf

I have a small static library compiled by (linux) gcc 4.8.2 with -fvisibility=hidden which is linked to a shared library (I have two versions, gcc one with C code and ifort one with Fortran code). The static library consists of some internal functions, all prefixed by "ST_LIB_".

I want to be sure that the functions declared in the static library cannot be used by any executable/library that is linked to the shared library. **What is the best command on Linux to check that functions with some prefix cannot be used by any external library?**

I have tried:

`nm --dynamic shared_lib | grep -i "ST_LIB_" | wc -l` (outputs 0)

`readelf -d shared_lib | grep -i "ST_LIB_" | wc -l` (outputs 0)

`nm -g shared_lib | grep -i "ST_LIB_" | wc -l` (outputs 26 or 0 depending on share lib)

`readelf -s shared_lib | grep -i "ST_LIB_" | wc -l` (outputs 26 or 0 depending on share lib)

`readelf -Ws shared_lib | grep -i "ST_LIB_" | grep -i "HIDDEN" | wc -l` (outputs 26 or 0 depending on share lib)

Comment: Why is `nm -g` giving you 26 results? `-g` (or `--extern-only`) should give you only externally visible symbols (exactly what you are asking for). So probably you have 26 `ST_LIB_*` functions that are not static.

Comment: static library is compiled by gcc, but i have a shared library compiled by gcc and a shared library compiled by ifort. The nm -g outputs 0 for gcc's linked shared lib, but 26 for ifort's linked one. That is why I am asking for command that really shows what linker reads

Comment: I wasn't talking about static vs. shared library. I was talking about the `static` keyword of C. If a function is static, it should be externally invisible to the linker. If gcc correctly tells you that there are no externally visible functions (with `ST_LIB_` prefix), but the ifort linker makes those functions externally visible, then perhaps there is something wrong with ifort, or something wrong with the way you call it.

Comment: the functions in the static library are not prefixed with static keyword, then they would be unusable in the shared library at all. I want to use the ST_LIB_ functions in the shared library, but I do not want the shared library to expose them further

Comment: Got it. Then perhaps you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9909528/912144)?

Comment: I am already using fvisibility option. I just want to test, if it works as expected (e.g. wrong gcc version can be used during compilation and I want to write an unit test that checkes the symbols in my shared library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nm --dynamic` should be the option you look for, since it displays the symbols you can link against (from a shared library). `readelf --dyn-syms` should display the same information (different output).

When using `nm`, check for symbols that have the `"T"` attribute. From the man page:

```
The symbol type.  At least the following types are used; others are, as well, depending 
on the object file format.  If lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the
symbol is global (external).  There are however a few lowercase symbols that are shown
for special global symbols ("u", "v" and "w").
[...]
"T"
"t" The symbol is in the text (code) section.
```

If you want to be 100% sure, you can always write a test program that links against your shared library and attempts to use one of the `ST_LIB_` symbols.